# install additional on azure for use with python webapp

Tags: python, dependencies, azure-web-app-service

I am creating a webapp using Dash. I have created the requirements file to install the different python modules I need.

One of the modules, Pyspice, works as interface to a program called ngspice. The question is how do I install ngspice on the azure app plan I have. I can see the app plan is running Linux. But how do I add this linux library so the python app can use it?

I have this documentation from pyspice, see 4.2
https://pyspice.fabrice-salvaire.fr/releases/v1.4/installation.html
But I don't know how to proceed.

UPDATE:

I created an startup.sh file which include

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install ngspice
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 app:app
```

Looking in the application log in azure shows that it install ngspice and the app start. But pyspice in python cannot do the analysis. So still some more needs to be done.

UPDATE:
Using the above script then to connect the pyspice to ngspice just use this command:

```
simulator = circuit.simulator(temperature=25, nominal_temperature=25, simulator='ngspice-subprocess', spice_command='ngspice')
```

So when defining simulator as ngspice-subprocess and spice command as ngspice then it works ! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can open an SSH session via azure portal, in your app service blade:
[image]

Also, you can open an SSH session in browser

Paste the following URL into your browser and replace  with your app name:

```
https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session

UPDATED:

To configure the startup command you must add the script here
[image]
More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-general-settings

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, you took me a little further. 
I now understand that you can create a startup script for the docker. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python?source=recommendations#customize-startup-command 
should i just include?
apt-get install ngspice

Comment: I created a startup.sh file including the following:

    apt-get update

    apt-get -y install ngspice

    gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 app:app